How to get all upstream and downstream documents in a doubly linked list in MongoDB?"
I have an entity in my application called Assign which I persist in a MongoDB database.
A kind of assignment history is stored in this entity. That collection has documents that differ slightly in some cases, but the idea is to have a Doubly Linked List (assignments are passed from one person to another), so in all documents there are two fields:
-next (id of the next assignment)
-preview (id of the previous assignment)

This is an example of the document:
{
  "id": objectID,
  "assignee": objectID of the Assignor Role,
  "assigner": objectID of the assignee (lawyer)
  "process": objectID of the process,
  "next": objectID of the next assignment,
  "preview": objectId of the previous assignment, 
  "assigneAt": time
}

Suppose I have an assignment that has gone through 5 different people. Now suppose I have the id of assignment #3, the idea is to be able to get the previous and next documents (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 5). How can I query this efficiently? Am I in the right direction?
This is a simple database example:
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664baf560b9539e48fbc6ed1"
  },
  "name": "fist assignment",
  "next": {
    "$oid": "664baf620b9539e48fbc6ed2"
  },
  "preview": null
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664baf620b9539e48fbc6ed2"
  },
  "name": "second assignment",
  "next": {
    "$oid": "664baf6d0b9539e48fbc6ed3"
  },
  "preview": {
    "$oid": "664baf560b9539e48fbc6ed1"
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664baf6d0b9539e48fbc6ed3"
  },
  "name": "third assignment",
  "next": {
    "$oid": "664baf8d0b9539e48fbc6ed4"
  },
  "preview": {
    "$oid": "664baf620b9539e48fbc6ed2"
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664baf8d0b9539e48fbc6ed4"
  },
  "name": "fourth assignment",
  "next": {
    "$oid": "664baf9a0b9539e48fbc6ed5"
  },
  "preview": {
    "$oid": "664baf6d0b9539e48fbc6ed3"
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664baf9a0b9539e48fbc6ed5"
  },
  "name": "fifth assignment",
  "next": null,
  "preview": {
    "$oid": "664baf8d0b9539e48fbc6ed4"
  }
}]

So, let's say I have assignment id 3 (664baf6d0b9539e48fbc6ed3). I need to bring the previous and subsequent assignments

Have you checked out $graphLookup?

Providing actual examples would be helpful, instead of 'id of next', 'id of previous', etc. In any case, you can get all the "previous" in a $graphLookup with previous & _id and then all the "next" with a separate graphLookup with next & _id. Start there and come back with a working example. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

I updated the question with an example from the database. I'll try $graphLookup. Can you give me your opinion on this approach? For this requirement, is it okay to design it like this? For example, I don't know if it is convenient to have all the next and preview in the same document (for example in document 3, have the references to 1, 2, 4, 5)

"for example in document 3, have the references to 1, 2, 4, 5" - No. Your document #3 (third assignment) only has a reference to one previous #2 & one next #4. Your example does not directly have a reference to 1 & 5.  And that is the correct way to do something like this - and it fits perfectly with the design for having a keyword like $graphLookup.

If refactoring the schema is an option, consider putting the chain in a single document(potentially use an array field to store all the assignments) to avoid costly lookup in NoSQL. If the chain is big enough to breach MongoDB 16MB limit, use the outlier pattern to potentially resolve that.
